# What is the most secure way of hashing password in PHP?

Tags: php

While stroring password i use password_hash()
My code is

```
password_hash('152207', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array(cost=>12));
```

But i found salt like thing in PHP too!
What should i use password_hash or salt while storing password in database?

Comment: `password_hash` includes a salt already. Just use `password_hash` and you’ll be fine.

Comment: There is no absolute "the most secure" thing. There is barely any "the most" thing in the programming at all.

Comment: Oh! Got it! Thank you!